# mysql update form using php issue keeps updating with old information not new updats

Tags: php, mysql

I am totally new to PHP and am working on an address book that contains companies and contacts for said companies. When click submit to update the data it just replaces it with the old data that was originally in there here is the companies html form:

```
<html>
<head><title>Update Records in MYSQL Database</title>
    <style>
        body {background-color: powderblue;}
        form {border: 5px solid midnightblue;
            padding: 40px;}
        label {color: darkblue;}
        form {border: 5px solid midnightblue;
            padding: 40px;
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //Connect to the Database
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '');
    //Select the Database
    mysqli_select_db($link, 'ADDRESS_BOOK_DB');
    //Select Query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Companies";
    //Execute the Query
    $records = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
?>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>CompanyName</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>ZipCode</th>
            <th>PhoneNumber</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
            echo "<tr><form action=update.php method='post'></form>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='CompanyName' value='" . $row['companyname1'] . "'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='address' value='" . $row['address'] . "'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='city' value='" . $row['city'] . "'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='state' value='" . $row['state'] . "'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='zipcode' value='" . $row['zipcode'] . "'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='phone' value='" . $row['phone'] . "'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type=hidden name=companies_id value='" . $row['companies_id'] . "'>";
            echo "<td><input type='submit'>";
            echo "</form></tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the actual updating php sql query that does not work or something any input would help get rid of this headache I have.

```
<?php
//Connect to the Database
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '');
//Select the Database
mysqli_select_db($link, 'ADDRESS_BOOK_DB');

//Update Query
$sql = "UPDATE Companies SET CompanyName= $_POST[companyname1], Address= $_POST[address], City= $_POST[city], State= $_POST[state], ZipCode= $_POST[zipcode], PhoneNumber= $_POST[phone] 
WHERE companies_id= $_POST[companies_id]";

//Execute the Query
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql))
    header("refresh:1; url=edit.php");
    enter code here

else
    echo "Not Updated";
?>
```

Comment: Less LOL, less bold, and more of a description of what the actual problem, please.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: the 3 ticks at the beginning and end were only put in there when I submitted to the lead developer on slack. So the 3 ticks were there after the errors started. I just forgot to get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks tadman I did not know this information you brought up. I will remedy this right quick I apprectiate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put here condition with `WHERE` clause `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Companies";` that which record from database do you want to update. It seems like you are fetching all the record from database inside `form` 
Second you have closed your `form` tag at the begening of the while loop and keep rest of the input fields without `form`
Change this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
        echo "<tr><form action=update.php method='post'></form>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='CompanyName' value='" . $row['companyname1'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='address' value='" . $row['address'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='city' value='" . $row['city'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='state' value='" . $row['state'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='zipcode' value='" . $row['zipcode'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='phone' value='" . $row['phone'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=hidden name=companies_id value='" . $row['companies_id'] . "'>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit'>";
        echo "</form></tr>";
    }
```

to

```
?>
<form action=update.php method='post'>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {

        echo "<td><input type='text' name='CompanyName' value='" . $row['companyname1'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='address' value='" . $row['address'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='city' value='" . $row['city'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='state' value='" . $row['state'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='zipcode' value='" . $row['zipcode'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='phone' value='" . $row['phone'] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=hidden name=companies_id value='" . $row['companies_id'] . "'>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit'>";

    }

?>
</form>
```